# How do I set up Buck with Dagger & Butterknife?

Tags: android, dagger-2, butterknife, buck

Hello my fellow developers,

I'm trying to switch from Gradle to Buck and have problems setting it up with Dagger and Butterknife since they need annotation processing.

I found a few links and tutorials, but they are already a few (~4) years old and I thought there might be a little bit newer approach on doing things.

This is what I looked at already:
https://github.com/ryan-endacott/android-buck-dagger-starter

Thanks in advance,
Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buck supports annotation processing for Java-based rules (including `android_library`). Take a look at how Immutables are used in buck repository ([link](https://github.com/facebook/buck/blob/master/third-party/java/immutables/BUCK) to source code):

1. First of all, you need to declare library jars:

```
    java_library(
        name = "immutables",
        exported_deps = [
            ":builder",
            ":value",
        ],
        visibility = [
            "PUBLIC",
        ],
    )

    prebuilt_jar(
        name = "value",
        binary_jar = "value-2.5.6.jar",
        source_jar = "value-2.5.6-sources.jar",
        licenses = [
            "COPYING",
        ],
    )

    prebuilt_jar(
        name = "builder",
        binary_jar = "builder-2.5.6.jar",
        source_jar = "builder-2.5.6-sources.jar",
        licenses = [
            "COPYING",
        ],
    )
```

2. Define annotation processor:

```
    java_annotation_processor(
        name = "processor",
        isolate_class_loader = True,
        processor_class = "org.immutables.value.internal.$processor$.$Processor",
        visibility = [
            "PUBLIC",
        ],
        deps = [
            ":immutables",
        ],
    )
```

3. You can then add this annotation processor to the list of plugins of the targets:

```
    java_library(
        name = "target",
        plugins = [
            "//third-party/java/immutables:processor",
        ],
        deps = [
            ...
        ],
        ...
    )
```

Buck repository [contains](https://github.com/facebook/buck/blob/master/DEFS#L16) a custom rule (`java_immutables_library`) that adds this annotation processor so that developers don't need to specify plugins on every target. You can probably use similar approach.

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm, after I got the hang of it.
Now my problem is that Buck can't find rx/functions/Func1, although I'm adding the dependency for rxjava and rxandroid.

Comment: I don't have enough information about this problem, but my guess is that your annotation process produces code with these imports, but the library that is process by AP doesn't depend on rxjava library (or maybe AP doesn't depend on rxjava). Any way, could you make a new post with more information here or on github?

Comment: I found out that the version of Butterknife I am using needs rxjava :).

But I have a different problem now: I managed to add Dagger and Butterknife processor, but I don't know what the processor class for javax.annotation is.